# Ponyfill Isomorphic-unfetch AbortController

Tags: reactjs, fetch, next.js

I am developing in React-NextJS using Hooks. Isomorphic-unfetch is used as a ponyfill:
`import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'`

There is a use case in which I want to cancel request. Can AbortController be used to cancel pending requests? I tried using it but it didn't work (as if it was ignored). So a little guidance will be appreciated.